# Can't create/write to file '/var/tmp/#sql_2f6_0.MYI

Tags: mysql-error-1064

For the past three to four months, we have our application live and running, we haven't deployed any new fixes / changes on `Live`. However ever unfortunately, we noticed that application has stopped running.

Following is the issue we observed from our logs :

> "Can't create/write to file '/var/tmp/#sql_2f6_0.MYI" .

It would be really appreciable if anyone of you can extend your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the services and the User for which your Mysql is giving you this error. It is very much possible that any of the services might be down, or the User by which you are using the DB is not getting authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

You or the user that handles your SQL service doesn't have permission to /var/tmp/. You can fix this by using chmod or Security permissions, depending on which platform you're on.

Comment: Thanks Bjorn, we found the solution